# For all orientation-preserving homeo is there a homotopic orientation-preserving diffeo?

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, riemann-surfaces, orientation, teichmueller-theory

Basically, I want to know if the following is true:

> Given an orientantion-preserving ***homeomorphism*** $f:R\to S$ between Riemann surfaces $R$ and $S$, does exist an orientation-preserving ***diffeomorphism*** $\tilde{f}:R\to S$ which is homotopic to $f$?

***The context of the question:*** I am reading a book (*An Introduction to Teichmüller Spaces*, by Imayoshi & Taniguchi) where, in a specific proof, they seem to implicitly use this fact, without making it clear. I don't know if this is really what they're using, but I've figure out that this would be suffice condition for the conclusion. (In the specific case, $R$ (and hence $S$) is a closed (i.e. compact) Riemann surface of genus $g$.)

If someone has the book and wants to look into this more closely, it is at the page 15, right at the second paragraph: "*To prove the surjectivity, it is sufficient to show (...)*"

Furthermore, if it is true, do you guys recommend some references to it? Is this a "well-known" fact? I'm a beginner ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping class group can be defined with diffeomorphisms.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_class_group_of_a_surface#Definition_and_examples

Since you can assume that $g:S\rightarrow R$ is a diffeomorphism. If $f:R\rightarrow S$ is an homeomorphism, $g\circ f$ is homotopic to a diffeomorphism $h:R\rightarrow R$ and $g^{-1}\circ h$ is homotopic to $f$.